# Is there a way to have a bitstype with missing values in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia, missing-data

For `Mmap` static arrays, we need the data to be a "bitstype" (have a fixed storage size in memory, afaik).
If a dataset has missing values, the typical way they are stored is that the column type is `Union{Missing,T}` where `T` is the type when it is not missing.
However, `isbitstype(Union{Missing,T})=false` even if `isbitstype(T)=true` (it also happens that `isbitstype(Missing)=true`).

Is there a a bitstype parametric type for allowing missing values in Julia? or generally for defining bitstype unions of bitstypes. I would imagine the size only needs to be 1 more bit (or, for practical reasons, 1 more byte) than the max of the two underlying types.

Otherwise, what is the "right way" to handle this case?

Comment: This needs either an array of boxes or a second array of type tags; read [this](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/isbitsunionarrays/).